# Unexpected behavior while measuring the connection duration using okhttp eventListener on Android

Tags: okhttp

```java
    import okhttp3.*
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.net.InetAddress
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress
    import java.net.Proxy
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    data class HttpTimeStatData(
        var conn_ts: Long = 0,
        var reqH_ts: Long = 0,
        var reqB_ts: Long = 0,
        var resH_ts: Long = 0,
        var resB_ts: Long = 0,
        var rt_ts: Long = 0,
        var event_ts: Long = 0
    )
    object HttpTimeStatListenerFactory : EventListener.Factory {
        val statDataMap = HashMap<Call, HttpTimeStatData>()
        override fun create(call: Call): EventListener {
            val statData = HttpTimeStatData()
            statDataMap[call] = statData
            return HttpTimeStatListener(statData) { releasedCall -> statDataMap.remove(releasedCall) }
        }
    }

    class HttpTimeStatListener(private val statData: HttpTimeStatData, private val onReleaseFunc: (Call) -> Unit) : EventListener() {
        private var resBStartMS = 0L
        private var resHStartMS= 0L
        private var reqBStartMS = 0L
        private var reqHStartMS= 0L
        private var callStartMS = 0L
        private var connectStartMS = 0L
    
        override fun callStart(call: Call) {
            callStartMS = System.nanoTime()
            statData.event_ts = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    
        override fun dnsStart(call: Call, domainName: String) {
            super.dnsStart(call, domainName)
        }
    
        override fun dnsEnd(call: Call, domainName: String, inetAddressList: MutableList<InetAddress>) {
            super.dnsEnd(call, domainName, inetAddressList)
        }
    
    
        override fun connectStart(call: Call, inetSocketAddress: InetSocketAddress, proxy: Proxy) {
            connectStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    
        override fun secureConnectStart(call: Call) {
            super.secureConnectStart(call)
        }
    
        override fun secureConnectEnd(call: Call, handshake: Handshake?) {
            super.secureConnectEnd(call, handshake)
        }
    
        override fun connectionAcquired(call: Call, connection: Connection) {
            super.connectionAcquired(call, connection)
        }
    
        override fun connectEnd(call: Call, inetSocketAddress: InetSocketAddress, proxy: Proxy, protocol: Protocol?) {
            statData.conn_ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - callStartMS
        }
    
        override fun connectFailed(call: Call, inetSocketAddress: InetSocketAddress, proxy: Proxy, protocol: Protocol?, ioe: IOException) {
            statData.conn_ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - callStartMS
        }
    
        override fun connectionReleased(call: Call, connection: Connection) {
        }
    
    
        override fun requestHeadersStart(call: Call) {
            reqHStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    
        override fun requestHeadersEnd(call: Call, request: Request) {
            statData.reqH_ts = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - reqHStartMS);
    
        }
    
        override fun requestBodyStart(call: Call) {
            reqBStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    
        override fun requestBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            statData.reqB_ts = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - reqBStartMS);
        }
    
    
        override fun responseHeadersStart(call: Call) {
            resHStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    
        override fun responseHeadersEnd(call: Call, response: Response) {
            statData.resH_ts = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - resHStartMS);
        }
    
        override fun responseBodyStart(call: Call) {
            resBStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis()
    
        }
    
        override fun responseBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            statData.resB_ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - resBStartMS
    
        }
    
    
        override fun callEnd(call: Call) {
            statData.rt_ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - callStartMS
            onReleaseFunc(call)
        }
    
        override fun callFailed(call: Call, ioe: IOException) {
            statData.rt_ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - callStartMS
            onReleaseFunc(call)
        }
    }
```

The okhttp version is 4.10.0. I used the above code to count the duration of each stage of okhttp call online users. Most of the results are normal, but there are also some very strange results. The calculated times are very long, even several hours, such as callStart and dnsStart, dnsEnd and connectStart. What may be the reason for this?

The expected result is that these values should all be within a few seconds.It should not be several hours or even more, this is not normal.